# Error in loading a pdf file stored inside the web application

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, pdf

Problem:

I have a number of pdf files saved in the resources folder of my web app. When I try to display the file in the jsp I am not able to. Below is the code snippet:

jsp file:

```
    <input type="hidden" id="myResourceFile" value="<%=request.getServletContext.getRealPath("/resources/myattmts/")%>"/>

    <div id="myrowid">
    <embed TYPE="application/pdf" align="middle" width=100% style="height:400px" id="pdfDoc"/>
</div>
```

javascript code:

```
document.getElementById("pdfDoc").src=$('#myResourceFile').val()+"'\'"+filename;
```

Error:

The pdf does not load as the file source delimiter '\ is not evaluated correctly.

Any help where I am going wrong

Comment: Is your web application hosted locally? After all you you retrieve the real file system path on the server (I assume by `gtRealPath` you meant `getRealPath`) and use it to address the file on the client.

Comment: are you sure to **double quotation** the backslash? ("'\'"). what happends when you remove the ' (single quotes) "\". And what happends when you use a *slash* instead of a backslash.

Comment: @mkl Yes. I that was the lacunae! :(

Comment: @Ben I didn't try that. But rather I used the File.SEPARATOR from  the controller to prepend the slash before the file name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am testing the web application in my locally. However it is to be deployed over a particular node after build and release.

The problem here was that the pdf file is retrieval only from the application context inside a jsp.

However when I use request.getServletContext.getRealPath("/resources/myattmts/") it tries to access the actual war file in the tmp/deployment server (the actual physical location where the application is running and the file is present). And is not able to read it from there.

Instead I changed the value of the hidden variable "myResourceFile" in the jsp to the application context path as

```
jsp change:
<input type="hidden" id="myResourceFile" value="<%=request.getContextPath("/resources/myattmts/")%>"/>

So the file path now reads as "`http://localhost:8080/app-name/resources/myattmts/fileName.pdf"
```

instead of the actual physical path (in the previous case which was not accessible to the jsp)
as "`E:/MyServer/deployments/tmp/app.war/resources/myattmts/fileName.pdf`"